# WebResource.axd & ScriptResource.axd loading takes more than 1 minute

Tags: webresource.axd

I have a problem. Sometimes WebResource and ScriptResource takes a lot of time to load, over 1 minute.
we have more than one nodes in a cluster.

Note that if you have a browser session is open before this problem, .axd files loads pretty fast. but new sessions loads those files sometimes 1 minute, sometimes 30 seconds.

Restarting nodes didn't help.

do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source project called [RequestReduce](http://RequestReduce.com) which can combine and minify js and css on the fly including Webresource and ScriptResource. I've seen it combine over 30 of these to one file in a single bloated page. Its a Response filter that runs in an httpmodule. The first few hits to your page will load the original contents while RequestReduce processes all the css/js files and caches them in the background. It also sprites and optimizes background images. You can download it at http://RequestReduce.com or install from nuget.